# What could cause an app in production to vary from development in such a way that all http requests become GET requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have an app that works fine in development on my local machine, but has several unexpected behaviors when I deploy it on Heroku.

First, the logout link stops working. In development, the logout link works by sending a DELETE request that gets routed to sessions#destroy. When you click the link in production it brings you to example.herokuapp.com/logout (which throws an error because the page does not exist) instead of activating the #destroy action.

Second, any other destroy links start behaving like show links. It's very similar to the logout link above, but with the exception that it shows the record to be deleted and does not delete it.

Third, I have a couple of custom actions #claim and #release that are both set to use a POST http request to activate the action. (the actions set the current user as the owner of a record, or sets the record's owner to nil, respectively) These both work well in development, but not in production. Similar to the logout problem above, clicking the claim link in production tries to bring the user to example.herokuapp.com/claim.1 (another page that does not exist) rather than claiming record 1 through the records#claim action.

I did some digging and found out that the source of all these problems is that in production, every request is being handled as a GET request. I could make the logout, claim, and release actions work by switching to GET rather than DELETE or POST, but this is a dirty solution and it won't fix the records#destroy action. I thought maybe Heroku didn't like the link syntax I was using so I tried changing the syntax for the links from this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', booking, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

to that:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', delete_booking_path(booking) data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

These links both work in development and neither works in production.

Both development and production are using Rails 4.2.4 and ruby 2.2.2p95. When I first deployed the project to Heroku is was using Ruby version 2.0.0, but I upgraded after these problems started to try and minimize differences between dev and production. I use SQLite3 in dev and Heroku uses Postgres in production.

I'm still new to development in general and tracking down issues over differences between development and production is particularly new to me. What else should I be looking at to troubleshoot this? Do you know of any phenomena that could produce these results?

Answer (score 1):

In order for `link_to` to work with the `delete` method, Rails needs the [unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).

- Make sure that your **Gemfile** has

  `gem 'jquery-rails'`
- Make sure that app/assets/javascripts/**application.js** has

  `//= require jquery`
  `//= require jquery_ujs`
- Make sure that your app/views/layouts/**application.html.erb** has

  `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`
  `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

  inside the `head` tag. Remove the `'data-turbolinks-track' => true` section if you don't plan to use Turbolinks.

PS: don't forget to check the console for JS errors in production. Assets are usually served differently in production compared to development. They are minified, concatenated, cached, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I'm going to check on all three of these today and I'll let you know what I find. Out of curiosity, how would missing one of these affect production on Heroku, but not development on my machine? Is there something about localhost being better able to handle the resulting faults? Thanks again!

Comment: Gemfile has `gem 'jquery-rails'` ; check.
application.js has `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` ; check
application.html.erb has two specific lines;  also check.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I have all of those pieces in place and taking out the Turbolinks part didn't help. But still thank you very much. I hope this will help others troubleshooting similar problems.

Comment: Did you check the JS console?

Comment: I watched the logs at https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/example-app-name/logs and I didn't see any JS errors. Is there a better place to look?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu's answer.

You should of course be diligent and not ship broken code to production but in some cases you may want to harden certain facets of your app so that they work even if javascript fails.

First a little basic knowledge about how Rails implements the extended set of HTTP verbs is in order.

Browsers generally only support POST and GET requests natively. To fake the other verbs such as `DELETE, PUT, PATCH` Rails relies on the [`Rack::MethodOverride`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/method_override.rb) middleware.

MethodOverride kicks in when a POST request is sent to the server. It looks for the `_method` key in the request body and changes the request-method header. So when Rails gets the request it appears as if it was a DELETE request all along.

`link_to` uses `jquery_ujs` to fake the extended set of verbs. `jquery_ujs` delegates an `onClick` event handler to links with a `data-method` attribute, this handler prevents the default action (sending a GET request) and creates a form in javascript and submits a POST request instead.

But when the javascript fails you just have a plain old anchor element and anchors in HTML only send GET requests.

But its sibling `button_to` actually creates a form containing a single button (along with some hidden inputs), thus it works even if the client has turned off javascript or there is a network failure (more common than you would think).

```
<%= button_to 'Sign out', session_path, method: :destroy %>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your answer helps solidify some advice I had gotten a while ago that didn't make sense and didn't stick. I had been told that it's usually better to use `button_to` for anything that's not a get request. But they didn't explain why very well so I basically forgot until reading your answer and it matched that half-remembered advice so well. I really appreciate you helping me understand the concepts and inner workings. Thanks again!